# how to remove border or change border color of CHeaderCtrl (mfc)

Tags: mfc

How to remove border or change border color of CHeaderCtrl? In my case CHeaderCtrl is embedded in CListCtrl (we are not calling CHeaderCtrl::create explicitly from our code). I would like to remove this white border from header or would like to change the border color.

[image]

Comment: I guess you have to owner draw for header list control ... might be something on codeproject ...

Comment: See here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/510/A-Multiline-Header-Control-Inside-a-CListCtrl

Comment: Is there a reason why aren't using the Common Controls version 6 and/or haven't [enabled visual styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175.aspx)?

Comment: By the way, you can look to implementation of `CMFCListCtrl` as a reference, as it goes with a different Header class than the default one. It is on the `X:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio <YOUR_VS_VERSION>\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\afxlistctrl.cpp` file or a similar path.

Comment: Look also to the .h file on X:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio <YOUR_VS_VERSION>\VC\atlmfc\include\afxlistctrl.h . The line `virtual CMFCHeaderCtrl& GetHeaderCtrl() { return m_wndHeader; }` says a LOT of a path good to be followed.

Comment: customDraw worked for me. But i can see that border flickers(Old White border appears ) whenever i scroll the list contents.

i tried to draw over in EraseBackground of CListCtrl and CHeaderCtrl as well.

Any idea on what can be done for this flickering issue?